# Custom media types with Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

How do I accept custom media types in Azure Functions (via HTTP trigger)?  If it matters, I'm using functions v2 and the durable functions extension (1.4) with C#.

I've read about custom media type formatters for Web API, but haven't found any similar advice for WebJobs / Functions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? could you explain your use case please ?

Comment: You can't - there is no content negotiation for Http triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions can support 3 types of webhooks: Generic JSON,GitHub,Slack. As kamil-mrzyglod mentioned that custom media types is not supported currently. I also find an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/317) related to it.

> not all of the various ASP.NET WebHook receivers are handled fully yet in Functions. We're currently only handling application/json WebHooks well at the moment, but not all of the other Content-Types.

My workaround is that we could handle it with our logic

```
if (req.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower().Equals("your custom media"))
{
   //var body = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   // todo
}
```